# Rails passenger not working with apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am trying to run rails using passenger and apache2 to I have followed everything but I am getting this problem.

```
Raw process output:

*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby: Permission denied (13)
```

I don't know how to fix it my apachecof file is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName nilay.com
ServerAlias nilay.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
PassengerRuby /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby
DocumentRoot /home/nilay/rails/pipe/public
RailsEnv development
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/nilay/rails/pipe/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my rbenv path is like this:

```
/home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby
```

I don't know what it the problem please help me fix this issue.

In my log I am getting this error:

```
            [ 2016-08-08 02:48:03.0084 3036/7f565b196700 Pool2/Pool.h:777 ]: Process (pid=5237, group=/home/nilay/rails/pipe#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
  App 5273 stdout: 
  App 3070 stderr: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `trap'
  App 3070 stderr: : 
  App 3070 stderr: Invalid argument - SIGKILL
  App 3070 stderr:  (
  App 3070 stderr: Errno::EINVAL
  App 3070 stderr: )
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `block in reset_signal_handlers'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `each_key'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `reset_signal_handlers'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:182:in `main_loop'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:161:in `<module:App>'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  App 3070 stderr:  from /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
  [ 2016-08-08 02:48:08.0183 3036/7f565b196700 Pool2/Pool.h:777 ]: Process (pid=5273, group=/home/nilay/rails/pipe#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
  App 5283 stdout:
```

And I am getting 500 internal server error

Answer (score 2):

Replace the value of `PassengerRuby` with the output from this command:

```
rbenv which ruby
```

Comment: I am adding this line   PassengerRuby /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby I am getting internal server error

Comment: Invalid argument - SIGKILL

Comment: Next step: try upgrading Passenger (see https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1362)

Comment: It is upgraded I think I had used sudo update 4 times

Comment: OK - please provide more detail from the logs (in your question) and your version of Passenger if possible.

Comment: See Updated answer

Comment: Is the web server running under your user account? The message says it does not have permission to execute ruby. If you are still having the problem, please check the permissions on the Ruby executable.